# Access TableView Outlet in popover which is not present

Tags: ios, swift

i have a problem with a downloadmanager in a popover.

Here is a example how i look like at the moment:

[image: downloadmanager]

When you click on any file in my Dashboard the file is automatically appended to my downloadmanager. But at the momemt i need to start every download with a click in my cell to download.

Now i want to start a download without the Popover is visible, and if i click on the popover i see the progress if my files.

The problem here is, that i have a IBOutlet for my table inside the downloadmanager, and that is nil when the popover isnt present.

So my whole FileDownloadHandlerClass is not working, because i have lots of references to my Outlet.

This is some code:

// create instance of manager in MainViewController

```
let manager = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FileDownloadHandler") as FileDownloadHandlerViewController
```

// On barButtonClick

```
@IBAction func downloadManagerButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: manager)
    let popover = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: navController)
    popover.popoverContentSize = manager.view.frame.size
    popover.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(sender as UIBarButtonItem, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Left | .Up, animated: true)

}
```

// this is how i try to start download

```
func addFileToFileHandler(notification: NSNotification){

    var fileObject:Files = notification.object as Files

    let fileurl = fileObject.url
    let filetitle = fileObject.filetitle
    let fileuuid = fileObject.fileuuid

// this is my global Files Dictionary
    arrFileDownloadData.append(FileDownloadInfo(fileuuid: fileuuid, title: filetitle, source: fileurl))

// Start first download automatically. (only for test, normally i know the cell index)
    manager.startDownload(0)

}
```

So is there a chance to make my IBOutlet accessable outside my class? Or other ideas? Or should i create my TableView for my Popover in my mainView and add it as subview, so i can access it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a global reference for your popover where your controller resides and initialise it once so the tableview will not be released when the popover becomes hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you see in my code i am already creating an instance of the manager == ViewController for Popover in my MainViewController. So the instance is still there, but my tableView is nil.

Comment: The `manager` is not the instance of the popover right? It is content controller of the popover. You declared popover locally as `let popover = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: navController)`.  Could you try having global reference for you `popover`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `manager` is not the instance of the popover right? It is root controller of the nav, where the nav is the contentController of the popover. You declared popover locally as:

```
let popover = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: navController)
```

Could you try having global reference for you `popover` something like this if it will work:

```
@IBAction func downloadManagerButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) 
{
     // if globalPopoverReferenceVar is not yet initialized
     if( globalPopoverReferenceVar == nil )
     {
         let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: manager)
         let popover = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: navController)
         popover.popoverContentSize = manager.view.frame.size

         // like this
         globalPopoverReferenceVar = popover
     } 

     globalPopoverReferenceVar!.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(sender as UIBarButtonItem, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Left | .Up, animated: true)
}
```